# Xcode 4.3 Black screen when adding tab page

Tags: tabbar, uicontrol

I'm trying to make a tab page based application in Xcode 4.3. First step is to add more view controllers than the 2 already there.

I drag a view controller form the library, then ctrl+drag from the tab controller, finally i create new UIViewController h and m file - named "CalenderViewControl" and select that name in the filesowner for my new added Viewcontroller.

Now everything seems fine in design - i have a new tab, referring to my new page.

but.....

When i run the simulation and select my new page tab, the page is all black, and nothing happens.
I have tryed to connect the file owners view to the view of the view controller - without any luck.

What I'm i missing....?

Ulrik

Comment: If i change the Filesowner class on my new view to one of the 2 already existing views, i'm able to see my screen....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you need to delete a method in your `.m` file of your new view controller.
 Just add some comment to the method called `(void)loadView` and you will see your new view controller display.

I hope to have been useful, I was stuck on that for a day and I finally figured out how to do it.

Good Luck!!